# Can spirit X3 work with BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion, boost-spirit-x3

Change my codes from QI to X3, and get some compile error with `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT`. I tried boost 1.64 and 1.67, neither of them work. I modified the spirit X3 example `rexpr_min`, adding getter and setter to `struct rexpr`, changing the `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` to `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT`, and compile it fail, too.

Enviroment:

- ubuntu 16.04
- G++ 5.4, with `-std=c++17` flag
- boost 1.67

Error message:

```
boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp:142:35: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘boost::fusion::extension::adt_attribute_proxy<client::ast::rexpr, 0, false>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘boost::fusion::extension::deref_impl<boost::fusion::struct_iterator_tag>::apply<boost::fusion::basic_iterator<boost::fusion::struct_iterator_tag, boost::fusion::random_access_traversal_tag, client::ast::rexpr, 0> >::type {aka boost::fusion::extension::adt_attribute_proxy<client::ast::rexpr, 0, false>}’
             return call_synthesize(parser, first, last, context, rcontext,
```

I guess the `fusion::front(attr)` return a const reference, and the `call_synthesize` want a non-const reference (at `boost_1_64_0/boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp`, line 146). But I don't know what to do.

I googled and find some regression of QI and they are patched in newest version. But there is no information with X3.

The original code [spirit X3 example `rexpr_min`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/spirit/example/x3/rexpr/rexpr_min/rexpr.cpp), And my modification:

```
/*=============================================================================
    Copyright (c) 2001-2015 Joel de Guzman

    Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
    file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
=============================================================================*/
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  A simple parser for X3 intended as a minimal starting point.
//  'rexpr' is a parser for a language resembling a minimal subset
//  of json, but limited to a dictionary (composed of key=value pairs)
//  where the value can itself be a string or a recursive dictionary.
//
//  Example:
//
//  {
//      "color" = "blue"
//      "size" = "29 cm."
//      "position" = {
//          "x" = "123"
//          "y" = "456"
//      }
//  }
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_adt.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Our AST
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
namespace client { namespace ast
{
    namespace fusion = boost::fusion;
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    struct rexpr;

    struct rexpr_value : x3::variant<
            std::string
          , x3::forward_ast<rexpr>
        >
    {
        using base_type::base_type;
        using base_type::operator=;
    };

    typedef std::map<std::string, rexpr_value> rexpr_map;
    typedef std::pair<std::string, rexpr_value> rexpr_key_value;

    struct rexpr
    {
        rexpr_map i_entries;

        const rexpr_map& entries() const { return i_entries; }
        void entries(const rexpr_map& ent) { i_entries = ent; }
    };
}}

// We need to tell fusion about our rexpr struct
// to make it a first-class fusion citizen
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT(client::ast::rexpr,
    (obj.entries(), obj.entries(val))
)

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  AST processing
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
namespace client { namespace ast
{
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Print out the rexpr tree
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int const tabsize = 4;

    struct rexpr_printer
    {
        typedef void result_type;

        rexpr_printer(int indent = 0)
          : indent(indent) {}

        void operator()(rexpr const& ast) const
        {
            std::cout << '{' << std::endl;
            for (auto const& entry : ast.entries())
            {
                tab(indent+tabsize);
                std::cout << '"' << entry.first << "\" = ";
                boost::apply_visitor(rexpr_printer(indent+tabsize), entry.second);
            }
            tab(indent);
            std::cout << '}' << std::endl;
        }

        void operator()(std::string const& text) const
        {
            std::cout << '"' << text << '"' << std::endl;
        }

        void tab(int spaces) const
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < spaces; ++i)
                std::cout << ' ';
        }

        int indent;
    };
}}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Our rexpr grammar
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
namespace client { namespace parser
{
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::x3::ascii;

    using x3::lit;
    using x3::lexeme;

    using ascii::char_;
    using ascii::string;

    x3::rule<class rexpr_value, ast::rexpr_value>
        rexpr_value = "rexpr_value";

    x3::rule<class rexpr, ast::rexpr>
        rexpr = "rexpr";

    x3::rule<class rexpr_key_value, ast::rexpr_key_value>
        rexpr_key_value = "rexpr_key_value";

    auto const quoted_string =
        lexeme['"' >> *(char_ - '"') >> '"'];

    auto const rexpr_value_def =
        quoted_string | rexpr;

    auto const rexpr_key_value_def =
        quoted_string >> '=' >> rexpr_value;

    auto const rexpr_def =
        '{' >> *rexpr_key_value >> '}';

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(rexpr_value, rexpr, rexpr_key_value);
}}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Main program
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char const* filename;
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        filename = argv[1];
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: No input file provided." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios_base::in);

    if (!in)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not open input file: "
            << filename << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::string storage; // We will read the contents here.
    in.unsetf(std::ios::skipws); // No white space skipping!
    std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<char>(in),
        std::istream_iterator<char>(),
        std::back_inserter(storage));

    using client::parser::rexpr; // Our grammar
    client::ast::rexpr ast; // Our tree

    using boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space;
    std::string::const_iterator iter = storage.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = storage.end();
    bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, rexpr, space, ast);

    if (r && iter == end)
    {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        client::ast::rexpr_printer printer;
        printer(ast);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        std::string::const_iterator some = iter+30;
        std::string context(iter, (some>end)?end:some);
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
        std::cout << "stopped at: \": " << context << "...\"\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. When I compile I get an error about line 100, should be: `for (auto const& entry : ast.entries())`. Fix, then x3 complains that the adapted container does not have a value_type. Using ms141

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Edited. @lakeweb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I've been [warning people before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37931344/85371)¹ you're pushing limits right on the intersection of things that frequently break Spirit's gears:

1. single-element fusion sequences
2. ADT adaptation in general
3. Persistent bugs with ADT fixed in develop (*after* 1.67.0 release)

### 1. The Single-Element Conundrum

I won't spend much time on this because it's a rather old, boring, well-documented² and not essential to your question.

Let's side-step it by adding a dummy field:

```
struct rexpr
{
    rexpr_map i_entries;

    const rexpr_map& entries() const { return i_entries; }
    rexpr_map& entries() { return i_entries; }

    void entries(const rexpr_map& ent) { i_entries = ent; }

    int i_dummy;
    int dummy() const { return i_dummy; }
    void dummy(int i) { i_dummy = i; }
};

// ... later:
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT(client::ast::rexpr,
    (obj.entries(), obj.entries(val))
    (obj.dummy(), obj.dummy(val))
)

// ... even later:
auto const rexpr_def =
    '{' >> *rexpr_key_value >> '}' >> x3::attr(42);
```

### 2. The ADT Proxy

The attribute-category machinery of Spirit detects the `entries` property as a container attribute (`is_container<...>{}` evaluates to `true`).

However the requisite container traits are not in place.

What's more, because of the restrictive interface that ADT proxies grant, the property values can **only** replaced whole-sale, meaning that we can only implement a very suboptimal version of it:

```
namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace x3 { namespace traits {

    template <typename T, auto... Other>
    struct container_value<boost::fusion::extension::adt_attribute_proxy<T, Other...> > 
        : container_value<typename boost::fusion::extension::adt_attribute_proxy<T, Other...>::type>
    { };

    template <typename T, auto... Other>
    struct push_back_container<boost::fusion::extension::adt_attribute_proxy<T, Other...> > 
    {
        using underlying_type = typename boost::fusion::extension::adt_attribute_proxy<T, Other...>::type;

        template <typename X, typename Y>
            static bool call(X& proxy, Y&& v) {
                auto u = proxy.get();
                bool b = push_back_container<underlying_type>::call(u, std::forward<Y>(v));
                proxy = u;
                return b;
            }
    };

} } } }
```

### 3. Surprise: Old bugs fixed after 1.67.0

You require the commits:

```
commit ae78e1ec2431517a8b0580099aeba8f9122d8abb
Author: Nikita Kniazev <nok.raven@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Mar 15 17:33:36 2018 +0300

    X3: sequence: Fixed reference to temporary bug

commit e7f31017ec7c0b5584d12ec1b718d8c415b26fa1
Author: Nikita Kniazev <nok.raven@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 14 18:54:35 2018 +0300

    Qi: Fixed ADT support by permutation and sequence_or operator

    This is follow-up to 0f2b3c49ce55a41a7d22cc5533e0f4ba59e491ae
```

These are more recent than 1.67.0 and currently in the `develop` branch. They (in part) fix an old issue: https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/pull/153#issuecomment-152879056. The current behaviour may also be impacted by commit

```
commit a0df3c098ff4e42c0958796c4f47d4d72a20c164
Merge: f73b121 fac9dfa
Author: Nikita Kniazev <nok.raven@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Mar 1 13:44:27 2018 +0300

    Merge pull request #370 from Kojoley/x3-pass-container-attribute-through-sequence

    X3: Pass container attribute through sequence
```

It's hard to gauge whether the impact is positive or negative in this ... turbulent landscape.

### Demo

Suffice it to say that **iff** you

1. compile against ae78e1ec243151 or later (`develop`)
2. Apply **both** the workarounds described above

**then** I see the expected output:

```
-------------------------
Parsing succeeded
-------------------------
{
    "color" = "blue"
    "position" = {
        "x" = "123"
        "y" = "456"
    }
    "size" = "29 cm."
}
```

(based on `libs/spirit/example/x3/rexpr/rexpr_examples/a.rexpr` input).

### Summarizing

I hope you don't think this is "fine". Please consider filing an issue at the mailing list/github. Also take these into account:

- [Is Boost Spirit X3 production ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237777/is-boost-spirit-x3-production-ready/48239766)
- [How future-safe is it to write a parser with Boost Spirit X3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014216/how-future-safe-is-it-to-write-a-parser-with-boost-spirit-x3/45015809?s=4|0.0000#45015809)
- In the light of recent recurring issues revolving arround container-attributes, I think a change around boost 1.65.1 caused container attributes to regress across the board:

  - [How to make a recursive rule in boost spirit x3 in VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48392993/how-to-make-a-recursive-rule-in-boost-spirit-x3-in-vs2017/48393573#48393573)
  - [Boost.Spirit X3 parser "no type named type in(...)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252680/boost-spirit-x3-parser-no-type-named-type-in/50260708#50260708)

---

¹ not to mention my dislike for it in most cases: [Using spirit to parse into classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581141/using-spirit-to-parse-into-classes/44585105#44585105)

² [Spirit Qi attribute propagation issue with single-member struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823413/spirit-qi-attribute-propagation-issue-with-single-member-struct/19824426#19824426), [X3, what is attr_gen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157367/x3-what-is-attr-gen/45161853), [boost::spirit::x3 attribute compatibility rules, intuition or code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37201023/boostspiritx3-attribute-compatibility-rules-intuition-or-code/37204957)

Comment: Very clear, thanks. Maybe I should change my AST to something just like POD, keep things simple.